# Doing DateTime Comparisons in Filter SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm a bit confused about filtering in SQLAlchemy.

I currently am trying to filter out entries greater than 10 weeks, so I have

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

potential = session.query(Subject).filter(Subject.time < current_time - datetime.timedelta(weeks=10))
```

However, the `potential.count()` always returns `0`.

My theory is that I am not using the filter statement correctly because when I try to use a column that is not of type `Column(DateTime())` but instead

> Column(String(250))

like

```
 potential = session.query(Subject).filter(Subject.string_field < current_time - datetime.timedelta(weeks=10))
```

SQLAlchemy will still not complain.

Also, when I do a manual check with

```
curr_time - session.query(Subject).first().time > datetime.timedelta(weeks=10)
```

I get `True` which implies that the count should not be `0`.

Am I missing something obvious? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you switch the `<` to a `>` you can get all subjects within the last ten weeks:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

ten_weeks_ago = current_time - datetime.timedelta(weeks=10)

subjects_within_the_last_ten_weeks = session.query(Subject).filter(
    Subject.time > ten_weeks_ago).all()
```

Filter generates a `WHERE` clause which *includes* results matching the clause. So the results are not "filtered out" but are included.

Answer (score 3):

OR if you use SQLAlchemy "and_" you can find all records between the dates:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_
#I use the .now(tz=...) because it is preferred over .utcnow()
#There is a waring on 
#https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage- 
#datetime
current_time = datetime.datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
ten_weeks_ago = current_time - datetime.timedelta(weeks=10)
subjects_BETWEEN_NOW_AND_last_ten_weeks = session.query(Subject).filter(
    and_(Subject.time > ten_weeks_ago,
    Subject.time < ten_weeks_ago)).all()
```

just another way of doing it! :)