# SQLAlchemy Datetime Differences

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, you can do a query similar to:

```
self.session.query(JobsRunning).filter((datetime.datetime.utcnow() - JR.start_time) > datetime.timedelta(hours=3)).all()
```

This fails because I'm assuming that `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` returns a double after being subtracted with `JR.start_time`. Is there a way around this without pulling the `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` outside of the query itself?

For some, this may make the query look cleaner.

Comment: This should work, is  JR.start_time not a datetime column?

Comment: Actually you should compare the column to the adjusted time, `JR.start_time < (utcnow() - timedelta(hours=3))`, as is done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868743/doing-datetime-comparisons-in-filter-sqlalchemy/17875113#17875113